# A discontented view of [contentview]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag [contentview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contentview) has [38 questions and no description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contentview).

## Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It is ambiguous as it refers to a UI element used in different frameworks. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75466426/contentview-not-updating) does not describe the content of the question at all, because it's the only tag that is being used, it doesn't even narrow down what language/framework it is. Furthermore, the issue is less likely to be the UI element itself, but probably some eventhandling (I don't have any idea; it never worked with [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/)). Featured frameworks include [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin), .NET [MAUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin#.NET_MAUI), and SwiftUI.

## Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Probably.

## Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

The tag adds absolutely no meaning. It is readily apparent from the code that a ContentView is used. It would be comparable to having a tag for the HTML `<body>` tag.

## Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I guess you could argue either way, but since it relates to different UI elements that may behave differently (as said above, I don't know about SwiftUI and Xamarin), I'm going to say **no** here.

Comment: I thought this process isn't required for tags with fewer than 50 questions?

Comment: It's not, but a 20k user has to confirm the decision before it can be axed, and it's useful to have all the details on the table both now and for posterity

Comment: Burnination is not the only possible way for an ambiguous tag. Alternative is *disambiguation*. E.g retag questions to `swift-contentview` and `xamarin-contentview`. Of course, if all new tags have a little meaning, disambiguation shouldn't be used. "It would be comparable to having a tag for the HTML `<body>` tag." - And such tag exists: [tag:document-body].

Comment: @Tsyvarev with only 267 questions this might just be another candidate.

Comment: @infinitezero Tags are not burninated just because there are "too few" questions where they are used

Comment: @Bergi I don't think it's a useful tag.

Comment: @infinitezero Well I do think [tag:document-body] is a useful tag

Comment: This post is missing a title pun.

Comment: "A discontented  view of `contentview`" @stickynotememo